# How to use Excel worksheet functions in VBScript?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I need to count the number of active cells in column `A` of Excel.
I can achieve this easily using 'worksheetfunction.countA' in Excel VBA, but unable to get the same in VBScript.

I have tried the following code:

```
Dim objXl , objWorkbook, objSheet ,numofactivecells

Set objXl = createobject("Excel.Application")

set objWorkbook= objXl.Workbooks.open("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\filename.xlsm")
'change filename

set objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

objXl.visible = true

objsheet.cells(1,1).select

numofactivecells = objsheet.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

msgbox numofactivecells
```

I need count of cells containing data in column `A` stored in variable.

I get the following error messages when I execute the code:

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected identifier
>
> Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected ')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few mistakes:

1. `WorksheetFunction` is a method of the `Excel.Application` object, not `Worksheet`.
2. `Range` can't be used by itself, it's a method of a `Worksheet` object.

Here's code that will work:

```
Dim objXl
Dim objWorkbook
Dim objSheet
Dim iActiveCells

Set objXl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objXl.Workbooks.open("C:\Temp\test2.xlsx") 'change filename
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

objXl.Visible = True

With objSheet
    .Cells(1, 1).Select
    iActiveCells = objXl.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A"))
End With

MsgBox iActiveCells
```

Comment: I still don't get the desired output after making the suggested edit. Can you please try once and check

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if this resolved your problem.

Comment: Thank you  Étienne Laneville. It works perfectly as expected.

Comment: My pleasure @Mahesh! Please accept the answer by clicking on gray check mark symbol on the left of an answer. A question with no accepted answer is rated as a not answered question even if there are good answers.

Comment: Thank you Laneville. I did.